# Bash Script Export fourth row in txt file to csv

Tags: bash, csv, export-to-csv

I have a 50 directories named as Subj1, Subj2 .. Subj50 each containing 152 text files each named in following naming format

```
regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt
..
..
regional_vol_GM_atlas152.txt
```

each file has data arranged in 4 rows and 2 columns, where column values are separated by space delimiter

```
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
9020 9020
```

I would like to export fourth row of each txt file with header into csv file for all 50 directories that i have

I have written a script which exports the data from each text file along with header and creates a CSV but the script takes in all the data inside the text file and pastes in CSV instead of 4th row.

```
#!/bin/bash


# pasting the file name as column name,  
for x in regional_vol_*.txt ; do  


   sed -i "1s/^/${x}\n/" ${x}

done
# Sorting the files and Subj1 directory name is file name of csv file 
paste -d, $(ls -1v regional_vol*.txt ) >> subj1.csv
```

The figure below describes the output of the file.Subj1 is a directory name

[image: Sub1output]

Comment: so you want to create 50 csv for 50 directories `Sub1, Sub2 .. Sub50` ..right? and each csv of the directory would have only header+4th row of each file .. right?

Comment: @ritesht93, No i want 1 csv file for all 50 directories with only fourth row of txt file in it along with header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` to recursively find desired files in all subdirectories and then use sed to pipe 1st and last row appended into a new file.

The main commands that performs all operations are:

```
$ echo "x" > temp
$ find . -type d -iname "sub*" | sed 's/^.*\///' >> temp
$ find sub1/* -type f -printf "%f\n" | paste -s -d , > data.csv
$ for dir in *; do paste -s -d ',' <(tail -q -n 1 "$dir"/regional_vol_*.txt) >> data.csv; done 2> /dev/null
$ paste -d , temp <(sed '/^\s*$/d' data.csv)
x,regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt,regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt
sub1,1 1,2 2
sub2,3 3,4 4
```

Here is a sample structure which I have made:

```
$ ls -R
.:
sub1/  sub2/

./sub1:
regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt  regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt

./sub2:
regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt  regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt
$ cat sub1/* sub2/*
header1 header1
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
1 1
header2 header2
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
2 2
header3 header3
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
3 3
header4 header4
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
4 4
$ find sub1/* -type f -printf "%f\n" | paste -s -d , > data.csv
$ for dir in *; do paste -s -d ',' <(tail -q -n 1 "$dir"/regional_vol_*.txt) >> data.csv; done 2> /dev/null
$ cat data.csv 
regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt,regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt

1 1,2 2
3 3,4 4
```

Comment: I need the output as a row not as a column, as you can see the from figure that i have attached in my question, i need output for each directory in separate row, so in end i will get 50 rows and 152 columns, each row representing directory and 152 columns paste the values of 4th row of each text file

Comment: @DevanDev do you need the headers of each file as well like I have put as `header1 header1` or you dont need that? You only need 4th row?

Comment: I need the headers. you can see the figure that i have attached in my question, i need csv exactly in same fashion with only 4th row , but for all 50 directories

Comment: I will check it now and see if i find some issues

Comment: It works fine but there are some issues, the file names are not in sequential order like regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt.... regional_vol_GMatlas152.txt, but the headers start with regional_vol_GM_atlas100.txt : [link to output](http://imgur.com/PyjwvRf) also is there any way to avoid repetition of header names for the files in each directory since in all 50 directories file names are same so one header is enough

Comment: @DevanDev you want the header form each file or you want the header as filename?

Comment: All 50 directories have files with same naming convention, if you see the link to output you can identify that all directories have files with same naming convention except the data in files is different, so i need just one header regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt ....... regional_vol_GM_atlas152.txt, and under that i wish to have all the associated  row values of regional_vol_GM_atlast1.txt  to atlas152.txt extracted from  50 directories

Comment: I am attaching the output [output link](http://imgur.com/QStn8P4), I need an output in this format [output desired](http://imgur.com/4Hbg7HY), where Sub1 ,Sub2 are directory names and in the first row i need the header names which would be files names of text files in every directory : that is regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt ....regional_vol_GM_atlas152.txt

Comment: @DevanDev filenames are already present as 1st row and rest all values are last rows of each file, i'll add the command to put 1st column as directory name

Comment: I will check it now, sorry for the delayed response

Comment: I am getting a strange output, the script generates 2 files , one temp file and data.csv and the output of data.csv is not appropriate : [Output of data.csv](http://imgur.com/vwr39vb)  and [output of Temp file](http://imgur.com/U3WcjnH)  you can see in the temp file, subject ids are not in sequential order, also its the same with data.csv file

Comment: The output that i am getting is posted in earlier reply, the output is improper